# Creating line feature with gradient based on data from the points that were used to create line using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology, display, points-to-line

I have air quality and GPS data in a table and can display these as points, but I would like to display them as one contiguous linear feature that "blends" the data and color gradient from one point into the next.

When I use the "point to line" tool, the resulting line doesn't have the data from the individual points that make it up and so I can't make it appear like a gradient.

I have this:

[image: The points represent a walking route, and the colors represent the amount of measured pollution]

And want something that looks like this:
[image: Just an example]

I can't seem to find a symbology way to make this happen.

Ideally, it would be great to be able to hover over part of the line, and the nearest point and its data are selected for view.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon that you need to create separate lines (line segments) between each pair of points, instead of one long line that traverses all points.  This way, each line segment can store the value of its start and end points.

Here is an overview (untested) of how I would do it (requires python):

- Create a new line feature class with two attributes, eg, "start_value" and "end_value".
- Using a search cursor (`arcpy.da.SearchCursor()`), iterate through the points feature class, working with details of the previous point (for all but the first point), and the current point.  In particular, the coordinates, and the value of both points.
- For each point (apart from the first point), create a new line (effectively a line segment), from the previous point's coordinates to the current point's coordinates.
  Add the new line (segment) to the line feature class.  Set the, eg, "start_value" value of the line to the value of the previous point from the curser.  Set the, eg, "end_value" value of the line to the value of the current point of the cursor.
- Now in ArcGIS Pro, you should be able to symbolise this new line feature class with a gradient, using the "start_value" and "end_value" values for each line (segment).